# How to get {{ pages }} object in a modular page

Tags: grav

Any thoughts on how to get the pages object in a modular page?

{{ dump(pages) }} returns null, but if I put the same statement in a regular page it works fine.

I have a page field that only gives me the URL of the selected pages and I need to get their title, ideally by just doing pages.find(link).title but "pages" is null for some reason.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you included an minimal, complete example of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using page find, you have to use the singular `page`, not `pages`.
example:

`{{ page.find('/contact').title }}`

That said, you being not able to access the `pages` object from a modular page is probably a bug that should be reported as I see no reason why this would not work.